# Can I change the preview image location (Dropzone.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

I would like to know if and how I can change the preview image location. I have designed a preview box with HTML and CSS and would like to know if it is possible to (re)place the preview image background-image url in my CSS?

CSS

```
.preview-overlay-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/file-upload/fileupload-examples/1.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="document-upload-box-upload">
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone dropzone-fileupload" id="fileuploadDropzoneImg">
    <i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true" id="fileupload-image-icon"></i>
    <p class="add-document">
      ADD IMAGE OR VIDEO
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

HTML (Preview overlay)

```
<div class="fileupload-preview-1">
  <div class="preview-overlay-1">
    <p class="preview-overlay-text-1">
      Click to add Caption
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="preview-image-1"></div>
  <textarea class="overlay-display-hide preview-caption-1"
    placeholder="Add Your Caption here..."></textarea>
</div>
```

JS

```
Dropzone.options.fileuploadDropzoneImg = {
  maxFilesize: 100,
  acceptedFiles: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,video/mp4",
  parallelUploads: 4,
  maxFiles: 4,
  addRemoveLinks: false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropzone has a parameter called `previewsContainer` which represents a container of files preview, and you can simple write `previewsContainer: "#previews"`, where `previews` is the id of your container.

f.e. (with jquery)

```
$("div#file").dropzone({
        url: "/upload",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoDiscover: false,
        createImageThumbnails: true,
        global: false,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        previewsContainer: "#previews",
        previewTemplate: document.getElementById('customTemplate').innerHTML
    });
```

Comment: _`$("div#file")`_ As we know, IDs have to be unique, so to specify it's a div is redundant.